# Wait until internet connection is checked (Xcode 11)

Tags: connection, wait, xcode11, swift5, verify

I want to check if the device is connected to internet. For it, I wait until i get a result (true or false). Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Network


let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

var connected = false

func checkConnection(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                connected = true
            } else {
                connected = false                    
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        completion(true)
    }
}

checkConnection { (status) in
    if status {
        print(connected)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I expected the value of `connected` changes, depending on whether I am connected to the internet or not. Instead of that, the value of `connected`remains equal to `false`.

Does somebody have an idea ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another way, simpler to do it: This class verify the internet connection (wifi or cellular) :

```
import SystemConfiguration

public class CheckInternet{

    class func Connection() -> Bool{

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }


        // Working for Cellular and WIFI
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

        return ret


    }

}
```

Then, in your code you check (and wait for) the connection:

```
func checkConnection(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if CheckInternet.Connection(){
            print("Internet connection is on.")
            self.go = true
        } else {
            self.go = false
            print("There's no internet connection.")
        }
        completion(true)
    }
}


checkConnection { (status) in
    if status {
        if self.go {
            // your code
        } else {
            // your code
        }

    }
}
```